# How to login in magento site from CI site and vice versa?

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento

I have two site on same(CI and magento) domain and placed magento site in CI root. I want to login into both site at a time i.e. when i try to login into CI site also login to magento site and vice versa.

Comment: I have call magento login function in CI but only login to CI site not into magento site and also tried login from magento to CI but only login to magento site not into CI site .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't place those two sites in the same root, CI and magento are two clearly different entities that need their own space to work fine.

Now if you specifically want this behaviour (Logging into CI also logs you in Magento and vice versa), you have to make a specific development to achieve it.

You need to locate the function called in Magento that logs you in and add your piece of code that logs in your CI site.

Then you need to locate the function called in your CI site that logs you in and add your piece of code that logs in your Magento site.

It should be hard to achieve, might contain security holes and in the end, might not be a viable solution at all.

Comment: Thanks. i have written magento login code along with my CI login function but when i try to login from CI only login to Ci not into magento

Comment: Thanks. It's Done. I written some custom functions.